# PHP Real path always returning false

Tags: php

I have a problem with the PHP realpath always returning false how ever I pass the file path string.

By default I pass this the the `realpath()` "/shop/templates/default/css/reset.css", I have also tried:

- http://localhost/shop/templates/default/css/reset.css

What could be causing this to break?

Comment: Realpath() works for filesystem paths only. Does `/shop/webapp/templates/default/css/reset.css` actually exist on your system? `/shop` being a folder in the root path?

Comment: Pekka, have you started posting comments instead of answers so that other people can post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Blair not as a rule, no! But I felt this specific case needed some clarification first. (Still, of course, everyone is welcome to post a fully fleshed-out answer from comments)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure you have the correct path? It probably doesn't start with /shop in the filesystem.

Are your permissions correct?

[realpath()](https://www.php.net/realpath) requires:

1. That the file / path actually exist.
2. Read permission for the entire directory hierarchy.

realpath() doesn't work with URLs.

Comment: You right thanks, I needed to pass absolute files like: C:\wamp\www\shop/webapp/templates/default/css/reset.css