# Facebook. api. How to publish photo on the user's wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have question how to post photo on user's the wall? I read many tutorials, but something goes wrong.
Last what i did, followed this tutorial:
http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-upload-a-photo-to-a-users-profile-using-facebook-graph-api/66/

I have set permission for publish_stream. I don't get any errors now, just not posting photo on the wall. Maybe something wrong with 
$file location... I don't know, please help me if you can. Thank you very much.

Comment: This actually helped me, so maybe it shouldn't have been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure the SDK is properly loaded.
- Your app requires `photo_upload` & `publish_stream` permissions.
- `$file` should be a relative path to your image. i.e ex: /path/to/image/file
- The POST param you're passing should be `image` and not `source`

So now the final version should look something like this (After you fix the above things):

```
<?php
require_once('images/Facebook.php');

  $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  ));

  # Get User ID
  $user = $facebook->getUser();

  if ($user) {
    try {

      # Photo Caption
      $photoCaption = 'My Photo Caption!';

      # Relative Path to your image.
      $file = 'plaukai/images/PlaukaiNeuzvedus.jpg';

      # Post Data for Photos API
      $post_data = array(
          'message' => $photoCaption,
          'source' => '@' . realpath( $file )
      );

      $apiResponse = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', $post_data);

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $user = null;
      error_log($e);
    }
  } else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,photo_upload'
    ));
    echo("<script>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>");
  }
?>
```

Note: I've removed setAccessToken/getAccessToken as those are not needed for this unless those were being used with the other codes, but otherwise its not needed as the SDK automatically passes `access_token` of the current user when your app makes any API calls.

Hope that helps, Let me know if you have any questions.

PS I've not tested the above code, but it has to work unless there is any other problem.

**EDIT 1:**

Try one of these solutions as well:

Solution 1:

```
  # Photo Caption
  $photoCaption = 'My Photo Caption!';

  # Relative Path to your image.
  $file = 'plaukai/images/PlaukaiNeuzvedus.jpg';

  # Post Data for Photos API
  $post_data = array(
      'message' => $photoCaption,
      'image' => '@' . realpath( $file )
  );
```

Solution 2:

```
  # Photo Caption
  $photoCaption = 'My Photo Caption!';

  # Absolute Path to your image.
  $imageUrl = 'http://placehold.it/500x500/'; // Example URL

  # Post Data for Photos API
  $post_data = array(
      'message' => $photoCaption,
      'url' => $imageUrl
  );
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here's the code you requested:

```
$redirectUri = 'http://domain.com/myapp/';

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
    'scope' => 'publish_stream,photo_upload',
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri
));

echo("<script>top.location.href = '" . $loginUrl . "';</script>");
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I use your code, I changed only `addId` and `secret`, but the same, no posting photo and I don't get any errors. I added `photo_upload` permission. Which one `"Auth Token Parameter"` I need to use? `Query String` or `URI Fragment`? Any Ideas what's wrong? I have code for "Publish text on the user's wall" this working correctly, I don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: My app still is on review `Live
Your App Detail page is live and available in search. Your app does not have enough high ratings and user engagement to be approved for listing in the App Center at this time. Please view our App Center Guidelines for more information.` maybe in that case can't be photo uploaded? And maybe do you know how many time I need to wait still my app will be approved?

Comment: Nope, That's not the case. And as for the access token, if you're using official SDK, you don't have to do anything. Also try changing `source` to `image` ? I've tested and it works fine.

Comment: I meant in `$post_data` change `source` key to `image` and then run the file, see if it works for you?

Comment: I changed to image, but still nothing happens. Photo not appears in my wall/album. This is good ? `$file = 'plaukai/images/PlaukaiNeuzvedus.jpg';` full dir.: `http://www.padekime.wu.lt/plaukai/images/PlaukaiNeuzvedus.jpg`

Comment: That's weird. Try this: Change `image` key to `url` and then pass full url. Example: `'url' => 'http://www.padekime.wu.lt/plaukai/images/PlaukaiNeuzvedus.jpg'` I tested this as well and it works fine for me. If this also doesn't work, then please post your error_logs.

Comment: Check my additional solutions I've added in my answer.

Comment: When I Deleted my app from "My apps list" and started It first time again after approved permissions I was redericted to `http://padekime.wu.lt/plaukai/index.php?state=f3870244f611c2e8df3eea407c2444c1&code=AQB1_-Ib73u6S423eo6Q8JtK0_-H-_j_WrXa0Hs3a2MVMCNPqjz1DGNiw54tvTaGbnkhL8BzD8pEF-6E83SlM6e0qtKt-xEGLa20J2AkDCCpPqIl3L476pYUFD3p-Ok84NBg4AObRPBPd-2kM__MyurPGIEyMh0Q-nWAZO7iUHnnZ1c0Rez__4ThT-dOrX6Du1f6wij56v6zlX4md8etlxsI#_=_` but I dont know why. All the time I were redirected to `https://www.facebook.com/Padekime/app_456080124457246` Why first time I'm redirecting to other url?

Comment: Pass `redirect_uri` to getLoginUrl function with the link you want the visitor to be redirected after allowing the app and it'll always redirect to that url.

Comment: OMG thank you!!! AFTER 10000 hours spent you gave me correct solution :) `Solution 2` worked for me. And how must look like with redirect_uri? And one more question. When I try second time login to my app (after deleted It) It trying login to https://... but why? And always when I try my program with other facebook accounts it use https protocol and I get error: `Looks like this page unsave... leave this page...` and I can't change from https to http... Thank you for everything.

Comment: No problem, Glad it worked for you :)

Comment: I've added the code you requested in my answer. And the reason why it automatically switches to `https` is because your account's privacy settings have secure browsing turned ON and you need SSL certificate installed on your server for that domain in order for `https` to work and that is mandatory by fb and i think by default its ON for all users now on fb, So you really need that certificate, otherwise you'll loose users.

Comment: And If you like the answer, you might wanna select this answer so this question is resolved and any visitors to this page will find the right answer, Just click on the `check` mark below the voting buttons on top left side of my answer.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. And how can I get certificate? Or can I change privacy settings?

Comment: You'll have to buy the certificate from either your host provider or domain provider or any other provider, But I'd highly suggest you to get one for cheap from namecheap.com as they have positiveSSL certificate which costs $1.99 (If you buy domain from them i think) from them. Most other providers sell expensive certificates which are good for big corporates or if doing any payment transactions through your application. Also changing privacy settings is not the right solution and I don't really recommend that. Just get that certificate as its cheap anyway.

Comment: Btw, The reason `source` isn't working for you is mostly because as per their docs, you have to `setFileUploadSupport` to `true` or `'fileUpload' => true` in the fb object array you pass, check out one of my previous answers which has the working solution here: [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12810351/828705)

Comment: Yes, that was reason. Maybe do you know how to publish user's name on Photo's caption when publish photo on his facebook wall? Something Like $user_name...?

Comment: You can fetch user's name by making a GET request to `/me` and then use `$user_profile['name']` anywhere in `$photoCaption` and it'll output user's full name. Ex: `$photoCaption = 'Hello ' . $user_profile['name'] . ', This is your caption' ` It should output `Hello Rs Penki, This is your caption`

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. Maybe do you know how long It takes: `Live
Your App Detail page is live and available in search. Your app does not have enough high ratings and user engagement to be approved for listing in the App Center at this time. Please view our App Center Guidelines for more information.` Or this means that my app never will be approved? I'm waiting for 3 days and I dont know how long still I need to wait.

Comment: It will not get approved until you have enough ratings and user engagement, So you should probably try submitting after sometime.

Comment: This discussion is growing too long and hard to follow. However it contains good information which should be integrated into the the question or an answer. Please do that and if needed, continue the discussion in the chat!